# how to handle user response to notifications in swiftUI

Tags: notifications, swiftui, response

i know how to handle user response to notification in UIKit, but how to do it in swiftUI.
swiftUI view are all struct and can't conform to UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, is there a work around?

Comment: It is hardly believable that someone conformed any of `UIView` to `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`. Handling is the same, there is nothing here about SwiftUI.

Comment: @Asperi got it! you've been helping me a lot! Thanks!